# Unit testing, statics, and factories

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, static-methods

I am implementing a model in Java which requires iterating over a collection and going through a number of identification stages, it involves for loops, while loops etc. It is the sort of thing I want to test at a fine-grained level so that I have confidence it has been implemented properly.

I have used it as an opportunity to start unit testing, as it is something I recognise as being beneficial to my code. I have since been reading a forest of books to get up to speed with JUnit and unit testing.

Basically my question comes down to two conflicting pieces of advice I have received:

1) Statics are evil. Do not touch statics. Do not test privates either, you probably want a class there instead.
2) Use factories for creation to allow dependency injection using parameters - potentially allowing use of mocks and stubs for isolation.

In my example I am looking to perform an operation along the lines of:

```
double height = 223.42; // this was set iterating over a collection of doubles
//blah
HeightBounds b = HeightBounds.getHeightBounds(height);
//more blah
```

I have done this in order to avoid building up what would become a very long and complicated block of code, which I can only test in its entirety. This way I have public accessible objects that I can test to ensure the system components all perform correctly.

Common sense says to me there is nothing wrong with static factories, and that they are easily tested, but am I missing something blindingly obvious given I am learning test-driven design?

Thank you

Comment: You should unit test every method that it makes sense to test, this includes static methods.

Comment: It is possible that "statics are evil" primarily is directed at static _variables_, since they keep their values between tests and might therefore cause dependencies between tests if they are not properly reset. Static _methods_ that do not touch static variables are not problematic, in my opinion.

Comment: the problem is that I could make my bounds checks within the class as a static method call but it would be very procedural and I don't want to list it in my public interface. One way I could test static methods without changing visibility would be to extend the class for testing and make methods to call them, but all the same everything I read people are saying "static methods are a code smell", you should be using classes. Given I am running in an embedded environment though I prefer the idea of avoid object creation as opposed to perfect OO design... still deliberating!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The static factory class introduces coupling between your class and the `HeightBounds` class.  this might make your class difficult to test, if for example `HeightBounds` goes off and looks in DB for information, or reads from a web service etc etc.

If you instead injected an `IHeightBounds` implementation into your class then you could mock that out so you could test what happens when the dependencies of you class do certain things.

For example what if `HeightBounds` throws an exception?  or returns null?  Or you want to test when a particular `HeightBound` is returned?  With an interface it is easy to mock this behaviour, with a static factory it is more difficult as you have manufacture the data to create the desired results in the class.

You could still only have a single implementation of `HeightBounds` and would be able to test that in isolation, but you would be able to test your method above without even having an real implementation.

I would probably have an `IHeightBoundFactory` interface and inject an implementation into the class.

As for testing the privates, generally you don't want to.  You want to be testing one of 2 things, either that the results are what you expected or that the interactions are what you expected.

If you have a method called  `Add` and a method called `GetAll` then you might want to test that when you call `Add` and then call `GetAll` you get back the one you added.  you don't care how this is implemented, just that it works.  this is testing the results.  Generally in this situation you want to create mock objects that return data.  This seems to be your situation.

If when you call `Add` you expect that what is being added is logged, then you want to test the interactions with the logging dependency, so you inject a mock dependency and verify that the interaction with that class happened when you called `Add`.  Generally in this situation you want to create mock objects that have expectations set, and you verify that those expectations have been met.  It doesn't look this is necessary in the situation you described above.

Comment: Not that I want to do myself out of the rep, but you might, in general, want to wait before accepting an answer, as more people may have a chance to give their opinion, or shoot my argument down :)

Comment: Ok thanks, will do as you suggest and wait for further feedback and finish addressing the other answers (which also cover lots of good content).

Comment: I am marking this as the answer as you were able to spot what I was trying to achieve and the concept I had misunderstood, then giving examples to fill in the gaps. Thanks

Comment: I am very good at open-ended questions :) I hit analysis paralysis quite often

Comment: This answer is strongly based on the *assumption* that a `static` method cannot be easily mocked... It's a bit strange that people usually take it for granted, even though the assumption is false.

Answer (score 3):

> Statics are evil. Do not touch statics.

"static" here probably means Singletons, i.e. global state. That is indeed difficult to use in unit tests, and can introduce lots of subtle issues, so it is better to avoid it in general. However, `static` members (fields, methods or inner classes) in general are not necessarily a problem per se.

> Do not test privates either, you probably want a class there instead.

This is true in general, if you feel the need to test a private method, it is a sign that your API is not fine grained enough, and the enclosing class may be trying to do too much. Often you may identify some coherent group of functionality which is better to extract into a separate class. This improves your design *and* in turn makes unit testing easier.

Answer (score 2):

A problem with static factories is, that you are not able to replace the factories (and sometime the objects created by the factories) by mocks. - That is one reason why IOC Containers are so usefull.

Comment: Thanks, IoC Containers was a very good keyword for google, I have since been reading this: http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html

Answer (score 1):

Static methods basically kill unit testing.

One of the basic ideas when you want to unit test your application is the ability to isolate different portions of your code. You usually do this by wiring mock objects for your environment. You can't wire anything if you are using static methods. Moreover, using static methods hides dependencies between objects.

In your last paragraph you say you want to learn test-driven design. If you are writing your tests *after* you've written your code your tests are not actually driving anything. Write your tests first.

Regarding private methods, you would usually have full test coverage of the public methods that use those private methods, so you are going to cover them anyway. If you have a really complex private method that you want to test (you should not) just use reflection to make it accessible. I'd rather break encapsulation than having untested code.

Misko Hevery has a very [nice post](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/12/15/static-methods-are-death-to-testability/) on this topic.

Comment: DistanceBounds itself does not exist yet - I am still fleshing what objects are needed and the process while keeping in mind how I will test them. Maybe TDD isn't what I meant, but basically rather than waterfall-style defining all my tests/code up front I am looking to write them as I come to write the code, method at a time ... certainly the tests are driving my design but yes maybe this isn't TDD or any formal process.

Answer (score 0):

Static methods are not evil per se. Look in JDK how many of them are there. Static methods also need to be unit tested, so if you have any go on and test them.

So it's not true that static methods kill unit testing.

But if you make statics only to write less code in unit tests then it is a wrong path since as others have stated you should better use your objects using your usual API - since this is what you want to test.

And full ACK for writing tests first - it will also help you design better API, cut you classes right.

Comment: The reason people say static methods kill unit testing is not because you can't test the static methods, but that the code that calls the static methods is difficult to test in isolation. In case of Java you'd have to use a framework that supports bytecode instrumentation (like JMockit) to mock/fake/stub/w/e the method. As I understand, it's not ideal (although I have only recently learnt about this possibility).

Comment: Well actually I personally do not know anybody saying that, so can't comment on "people say". For me "kill unit testing" sounds like "now that you have static methods you're in real trouble and can't unit test" which is plain not true (as I stated). True is that is makes testing more difficult, yet not impossible. And there are times where static methods are beneficial. And once you have them you should test them. Like you stated is mocking one of the possibilities, pretty good I'd say. Other is to prepare the state so that tests work - I did it more than once, it is definitely possible.

Comment: I assumed that your statement "So it's not true that static methods kill unit testing." was a response to the opposite. The reason I commented is because I felt your answer says "static methods are OK to use because you can also test them" and I wanted to add what I understand to be the downsides: Mocking them is difficult because it's more complex and also slower than normal mocking. In general you want your unittests to be simple (so you can maintain them) and fast (so you can run them often).